# Align nested div and scale without shifting

Tags: html, css

Div 1 is set with an bg, which has a window in its image.
I want to align a div at the position of this window and scale it, but it keeps wandering up or down when I scale my browser in width.

Sorry if there is a minor thing that fixes it, I'm still new to CSS and I can't find any answers to this question :/

I learned from fiddle through searching for this... so I hope I did it right:

```
    .bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  z-index : 1;
    height: 300%;


    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: visible;

    animation: fadein 2s;

  background-color: blue;
    background-position: top-left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
 }

 #display{
   z-index : 2;
    position: relative;

    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow:hidden;

  background-color: red;

}
```

(url -> pls see edit)
imagine a window in the middle of the blue div.
The div does not line up in height and width yet, but if it would, when you scale the container the div squishes but does not follow the new x position.

edit:
https://jsfiddle.net/acf8unsj/7/
made an actual window as bg and aligned the div. Now you can see what i mean by simply squishing the window.

also, height is by 300% so the page is scrollable (the actual background is a 4032px height jpg)

Comment: show your code, don't describe it only

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: addet code and fiddle. I should have done that bevor submitting. It took a while to edit it, im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

although the question is not described well but i know what do you want.
you cannot achieve that by absolute position and percentage. the best way to do such thing is to use **Image Map**:

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x500" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="271,167,559,337" shape="rect">
</map>
```

there are many online image map generators to make your work easy.

for example : https://www.image-map.net/

and then color it using a jquery plugin. for example :

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Highlighting-Image-Map-Maphilight.html